# Exchange Server 2010 calendar items reappear after deleting

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010, calendar

I have an issue with Exchange 2010 that I have never seen before. Two days ago, a user reported that a bunch of calendar items kept popping up on their screen as reminders in Outlook. I assumed a corrupt calendar item, ran CalCheck, deleted about 1,700 corrupt calendar items, and thought it was fixed. Then the items came back again.

I have tried everything I can think of:

- Removed all ActiveSync connections
- Deleted the mailbox and recreated it
- Rebooted my CAS and database server
- Attempted to purge the items with searches

I honestly don't know what else to do. About every five to ten minutes, roughly 140 calendar items populate themselves in this user's calendar, pop up as reminders, then delete themselves to the Deleted Items folder. It seems like something stuck in a queue, but I don't know where to look. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen in OWA when you deleted calendars in OWA?

Is he using other calendar synchronization software, such as Google Calendar Sync? If so, delete these calendars from his calendar sync software to fix the issue, and check if it continues.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually resolved this, but didn't update here since no one had commented.

Deleting in OWA didn't fix it. I ended up having to use Shift+Delete to get rid of most of them, then I turned off all of the connection policies (ActiveSync, MAPI, etc) overnight, and that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I'v glad your issue has been resolved :)